# Streaming voice over tcp

Tags: java, android, tcp

I've coded an app that streams audio over TCP from client to server but it does not work, i.e. no audible output. Could you check my code tell me whats wrong with it?

**Client:**

```
public void startStreaming() {


   Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
            try {

                int minBufSize =AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                Log.d("VD ", "Bufer intioalised "+minBufSize);

                short[] buffer=new short[minBufSize];


                Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size .c" + minBufSize);
              //  DatagramPacket packet;

                final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName(target.getText().toString());
                port=Integer.parseInt(target_port.getText().toString());

                Socket socket=new Socket(destination,port);

                DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved.c");


                if (minBufSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized.c");}


                if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED){
                    Log.d("VS", "Recorder working....c");
                    recorder.startRecording();}

                BufferedWriter input;
                while(status == true) {


                    //reading data from MIC into buffer
                  int  bufferReadResult = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);


                      dos.write(buffer,0,bufferReadResult);

                  dos.flush();



                }

            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException message:",e.getMessage().toString());


            }



        }
```

**Server:**

public void startStreaming() {
    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
    @Override
    public void run() {



        try {

            int  minBufSize =1024;//recorder.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat);


            ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(50005);



             // DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(50005);


              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


                  if (minBufSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {



                      speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


                      speaker.play();
                      Log.d("VR", "spekaer playing...");
                  }
            //  }




                  Log.d("VR", ""+status);
                  BufferedReader input;
                  InputStream is;
                  ObjectInputStream ois;
                  ByteArrayInputStream baiss;
                  socket = serversocket.accept();
                    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));


                        while(status == true) {

                              //DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

                            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

                            Log.d("content :", socket.getOutputStream().toString());


                            int i=0;
                            while (dis.available() > 0 && i < buffer.length) {
                                buffer[i]=(byte) dis.readShort();
                              i++;
                            }

       speaker.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);
```

Please give me your best help.

Comment: please stop editing my question. help me with this problem

Comment: Please explain first how this should work. Then explain which parts work ok. Then explain wich problem you have exactly. Once you have done that we will have a look at the code.

Comment: hello. tnx to replyaing... i got it working a little bit now.i was changing my code whole the night. so it is working now but there is still problem. problem is it's too noisy.there is voice transitions but too nosy. so i edited my first post for you to look at it. thanks.

Comment: Please explain first how this should work. Then explain which parts work ok. Then explain wich problem you have exactly. Once you have done that we will have a look at the code.

Comment: server listens on a specific port client get the ip of server then connect to it.DataOutputStream  Gets the socket information. client starts recording and puts in buffer. then flush it to server. server is listening on a specific port as client connect .DataOutputStream  Gets the Client's socket information then plays the voice.difficult to expalin step by step

Comment: int  bufferReadResult = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                  for (int i=0; i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                      dos.write(buffer.toString().getBytes());
                    }
                  Can you tell what you are trying to do with that code?

Comment: recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) puts the recorded audio in buffer. then with a simple loop make it as a Bytes and send(flush) it to server. do you what is my problem now?? i transmit the voice but repeated beep.!!! not clear voice

Comment: Nonsense coding. You do not need a loop to send that buffer. If bufferReadResult is for instance 800 then you send 800 times that complete buffer.  Moreover you first convert the bytes in that buffer to a String and then with getBytes() to bytes again. The result is also  that you send different bytes as were recorded in the buffer.

Comment: will you change that part for me?

Comment: No loop. Only dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferReadResult);

Comment: okay. remove the loop. now it's better than before.but still noisy no clear voice. Edited fist post

Comment: 'dis.readShort();'. You should not read byte for byte. read the whole buffer at once. Change your server code so it looks like that on client where you read in a buffer and then write the buffer.

Comment: 'InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();' Take that out of the loop. Place it just before the while.

Comment: greenapps  you made my day. i changed my code as you said. now it's working very well. thanks a billion. i wana vote you up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are in the comments. Both for server and client read()/write() had to be implemented better.

Comment: will you cheek my new tpic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584287/cant-we-use-audiotrack-and-audiorecord-in-same-project

Comment: could you share full code, I have similar issue, sending pc microphone voice over tcp ip to android.